# Use CSS and HTML only to activate the <animate /> tag?

Tags: html, css, animation, svg

I have the following code:

Is there a way to **activate** the `<animate />` tag using only HTML and CSS? Only when **activated**, should the animation rules of `<animate />` be executed.  For example, is there some new HTML CSS standard in recent years or coming up in 2020 that will let me do something like `input:checked ~ svg animate {enabled:true;}`?  Or something else fancy?

I want to completely avoid JavaScript in my project to challenge and amuse myself.

```html
  <body>
     <input type="checkbox" />
     <svg class="curtain home" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
      <defs>
        <pattern id="img1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="100" height="100">
       <image xlink:href="https://picsum.photos/id/1000/800/800" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" />
        </pattern>
      </defs>
      <polygon points="0,0 0,100 100,100 50,0" fill="url(#img1)">
       <animate attributeName="points" dur="5s" values="0,0 0,100 100,100 50,0 ; 50,40 30,60 80,10 50,70; 0,0 0,100 100,100 50,0" keyTimes="0;0.5;1" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
      </polygon>
     </svg> 
    </body>
```

---

ADDITIONAL

I am open to other options that give the illusion that no animation was running until the input field is checked.  Or maybe having another HTML element that works well with the `<animate />` tag to give the illusion animation can start and stop based on user interaction with the webpage.

Comment: If someone knows how to animate the points attribute with css, you could probably use the adjacent selector of the input element and put it in the code as a sibling to the svg. E.g. `input:checked+svg>polygon{ animation: ... }`

Comment: Also there are plans to remove SMIL animations in favor of CSS ( probably in the very far future or never as they probably do not want to break working svg-code ). https://www.w3.org/TR/web-animations/#relationship-to-other-specifications

Comment: @RMo I added a CSS solution to my answer if intrested ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can probably consider a trick where you toggle the display of two polygon

```css
.hide {
  display:none;
}

input:checked~svg .hide {
  display:block;
}
input:checked~svg .show {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <input type="checkbox" >
  <svg class="curtain home" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
        <defs>
          <pattern id="img1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="100" height="100">
            <image xlink:href="https://picsum.photos/id/1000/800/800" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" />
          </pattern>
        </defs>
        <polygon points="0,0 0,100 100,100 50,0" fill="url(#img1)" class="show">
        </polygon>
        <polygon points="0,0 0,100 100,100 50,0" fill="url(#img1)" class="hide">
            <animate attributeName="points" dur="5s" values="0,0 0,100 100,100 50,0 ; 50,40 30,60 80,10 50,70; 0,0 0,100 100,100 50,0" keyTimes="0;0.5;1" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
        </polygon>
    </svg>
</body>
```

Or use the click event. The trick is to have two rect, one for the begin and the other for the end. With some CSS you make them above each other and you play with z-index:

Here is a basic example, you simply need to find a good way to make the red rect look better since it will be the one you have to click one.

```css
label {
  position:absolute;
  z-index:0;
}

input:checked + label {
 z-index:1;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <input type="checkbox" id="input" >
  <label for="input"><svg viewBox="0 0 10 10" height="20">
        <rect id="stop" x=0 y=0 width="100%" height="100%" fill="red" />
  </svg></label>
  <label for="input"><svg viewBox="0 0 10 10" height="20">
        <rect id="start" x=0 y=0 width="100%" height="100%" fill="red" />
  </svg></label>

  <svg class="curtain home" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
        <defs>
          <pattern id="img1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="100" height="100">
            <image xlink:href="https://picsum.photos/id/1000/800/800" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" />
          </pattern>
        </defs>
        <polygon points="0,0 0,100 100,100 50,0" fill="url(#img1)" class="hide">
            <animate attributeName="points" begin="start.click" end="stop.click"  dur="5s" values="0,0 0,100 100,100 50,0 ; 50,40 30,60 80,10 50,70; 0,0 0,100 100,100 50,0" keyTimes="0;0.5;1" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
        </polygon>
    </svg>
</body>
```

If you are intrested in a CSS-only solution this can be done easily with few lines code:

```css
img {
  width: 400px;
  display:block;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0 100%, 100% 100%, 50% 0);
  animation:change 5s linear infinite paused;
}
input:checked + img {
  animation-play-state:running;
}

@keyframes change{
  50% {
    clip-path: polygon(50% 40%, 30% 60%, 80% 10%, 50% 70%)
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" >
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1000/800/800">
```

Comment: hehe, I was doing that, but when toggling between the two elements, the animated element might already be at t=3s into the animation, instead of appearing as if it started from t=0s.  I guess I'd have to something cosmetic like some kind of fade effect to smooth it out?

Comment: I wonder...if CSS has some kind of `time` or `delay` feature. I'll make 10 different copies of the SVG, each with a delayStartTime greater than the next.  Then make multiple copies of `input`, then use CSS animation to cycle the z-index of each based on some delayStartTime or something.  And then each input checkbox will match and SVG with a corresponding delayOffSet.  Or something silly like that?

Comment: @John I don't think it would be possible like that. Generally there is no trivial CSS .. I added another trick, it can probably give more ideas

Comment: @John updated the example to add a start and end ;) it should be better

Comment: @John These are the most standard ways to control animations.  In addition, you can use a bunch of other conditions. In short, we say that this animation will start after the end of this animation or with a delay of 2 s begin = "an.end + 2s" or 1 second before the end  begin = "an.end - 1s   Please ask another question more difficult with timings and see how surprisingly simple it is solved in svg compared to css

Comment: @John added a CSS solution since I think it more suitable and easier here ;) ... I am also a CSS guy :p

Comment: @John I do not criticize in any way :) Just svg somehow forgotten disappeared in the background. But for the sake of objectivity, svg animation does not need to worry about synchronization time, when many animations are intertwined in parallel, sequentially and all this can be expressed using human logic in human language.

Comment: @TemaniAfif  I can't seem to get clip-path animation to work in Chrome: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59313336/webkit-clip-path-not-working-for-chrome