# -webkit-clip-path not working for Chrome?

Tags: css, google-chrome, clip-path

The following code works fine in FireFox and it shows a blue bunny rabbit:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <style>
#item1 {
  display:block;
  width:500px;
  height:500px;
  background:#369;
  clip-path: path('m 29.937786,284.5542 c -5.893949,-2.10071 -16.137808,-1.46109 -20.6689304,-4.19599 c -30.9424776,-93.41773 40.1491104,-99.87798 39.9169904,-130.49916 c -4.155883,-11.91356 -1.37483,-24.01298 3.09354,-30.76224 c -8.719524,-8.5724 -13.651389,-22.766307 -12.09846,-33.358522 c 1.543697,-12.047112 12.084392,-3.353633 12.65133,-4.22669 c -1.80717,-4.26947 -1.33755,-7.49019 1.282784,-8.79738 c 12.780242,-1.845839 15.499482,18.964276 17.971662,29.907252 c 17.187,4.59876 36.431048,12.02357 44.555168,30.48952 c 0.0513,5.79697 3.28251,6.00908 3.12021,11.4242 c -2.6378,15.76105 -27.345338,10.04675 -20.137208,27.02235 c 10.993518,24.31925 -13.81309,43.57354 2.027808,76.88013 c 1.127,2.07114 0.9668,3.65716 -1.30438,4.51239 c -7.861908,1.59894 -13.930178,-5.3055 -16.538058,-10.32425 c 1.42688,12.55744 -1.54424,25.85645 -6.00534,32.78576 c 26.569178,3.44452 30.242508,14.30155 5.231,14.20239 c -17.56971,-4.74981 -36.54354,-3.32533 -53.098116,-5.05976 z');
  -webkit-clip-path: path('m 29.937786,284.5542 c -5.893949,-2.10071 -16.137808,-1.46109 -20.6689304,-4.19599 c -30.9424776,-93.41773 40.1491104,-99.87798 39.9169904,-130.49916 c -4.155883,-11.91356 -1.37483,-24.01298 3.09354,-30.76224 c -8.719524,-8.5724 -13.651389,-22.766307 -12.09846,-33.358522 c 1.543697,-12.047112 12.084392,-3.353633 12.65133,-4.22669 c -1.80717,-4.26947 -1.33755,-7.49019 1.282784,-8.79738 c 12.780242,-1.845839 15.499482,18.964276 17.971662,29.907252 c 17.187,4.59876 36.431048,12.02357 44.555168,30.48952 c 0.0513,5.79697 3.28251,6.00908 3.12021,11.4242 c -2.6378,15.76105 -27.345338,10.04675 -20.137208,27.02235 c 10.993518,24.31925 -13.81309,43.57354 2.027808,76.88013 c 1.127,2.07114 0.9668,3.65716 -1.30438,4.51239 c -7.861908,1.59894 -13.930178,-5.3055 -16.538058,-10.32425 c 1.42688,12.55744 -1.54424,25.85645 -6.00534,32.78576 c 26.569178,3.44452 30.242508,14.30155 5.231,14.20239 c -17.56971,-4.74981 -36.54354,-3.32533 -53.098116,-5.05976 z');
}

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="item1"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

But when I look at this same code in Chrome, I just see a blue square.  The caniuse dot com website says that there is partial support for `clip-path`.  Have I done something wrong that prevents Chrome from showing my bunny clip path?

Comment: this is not the correct syntax for clip-path .. you are adding an SVG syntax of path inside clip-path. It doesn't work like that

Comment: @TemaniAfif I wrote an answer to my own question below but I am not convinced it is the correct solution because it causes this animation problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59440805/unable-to-transition-or-animate-css-clip-path . Do you have any feedback for any of these questions? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work

```css
.svg-clipped {
    clip-path: url(#svgRabbit);
    -webkit-clip-path: url(#svgRabbit);
    background:black;
    width:200px;
    height:500px;
}
```

```html
        <div class="svg-clipped"></div>
        <svg height="0" width="0">
            <defs>
                <clipPath id="svgRabbit">
                    <path fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1.5794" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="m 29.937786,284.5542 c -5.893949,-2.10071 -16.137808,-1.46109 -20.6689304,-4.19599 c -30.9424776,-93.41773 40.1491104,-99.87798 39.9169904,-130.49916 c -4.155883,-11.91356 -1.37483,-24.01298 3.09354,-30.76224 c -8.719524,-8.5724 -13.651389,-22.766307 -12.09846,-33.358522 c 1.543697,-12.047112 12.084392,-3.353633 12.65133,-4.22669 c -1.80717,-4.26947 -1.33755,-7.49019 1.282784,-8.79738 c 12.780242,-1.845839 15.499482,18.964276 17.971662,29.907252 c 17.187,4.59876 36.431048,12.02357 44.555168,30.48952 c 0.0513,5.79697 3.28251,6.00908 3.12021,11.4242 c -2.6378,15.76105 -27.345338,10.04675 -20.137208,27.02235 c 10.993518,24.31925 -13.81309,43.57354 2.027808,76.88013 c 1.127,2.07114 0.9668,3.65716 -1.30438,4.51239 c -7.861908,1.59894 -13.930178,-5.3055 -16.538058,-10.32425 c 1.42688,12.55744 -1.54424,25.85645 -6.00534,32.78576 c 26.569178,3.44452 30.242508,14.30155 5.231,14.20239 c -17.56971,-4.74981 -36.54354,-3.32533 -53.098116,-5.05976 z"/>
                </clipPath>
            </defs>
        </svg>
```